# How to elegantly initialize a Scala service from a database?

Tags: scala, monads, future, option-type

I've been away from Scala for a while, so I'm trying to get back into the idioms. I have three database calls:

```scala
db.getInventory(inventoryId: UUID): Future[Option[Inventory]]
db.getInventoryFields(inventoryId: UUID): Future[Seq[InventoryField]]
db.allInputs: Future[Seq[Input]]
```

If `db.getInventory` is `Some(inventory)`, I want to initialize my service by giving it a

```scala
CacheContext(inventory: Inventory, fields: Seq[InventoryField], inputs: Seq[Input])
```

but if it's None, I want to report and error and return.

What is the best combination of `for`/`map`/`flatMap`/`fold` etc to use here?

Comment: By "report an error" do you actually want to throw an error or push the error up the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a `Future[Option[CacheContext]]`.

```
for {
  optInv  <- db.getInventory(theUuid)
  invFlds <- db.getInventoryFields(theUuid)
  inputs  <- db.allInputs
} yield optInv.map(CacheContext(_,invFlds,inputs))
```

Unpacking the `Future` (i.e. waiting) should be done much later in the code (if ever), at which point you can `.fold()` over the `Option` and report the error.